# Typescript errors in SharePoint Framework webparts

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I created a new sharePoint framework  webpart using  the msdn link

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

After Executing the **gulp serve**  commands i got the below errors. please check the below image.
[image]

Can anyone help me on how to fix the issue. as per the descriptions, the error are in the Typescript.

Comment: Can you run `npm i -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest` and recreate the project ? Looks like old version of SPFx

Comment: @Gautam Sheth Thanks for the quick response.  Will try and update you..

Comment: @Gautam Sheth : This time iam getting another error as below.
C:\spfxwebparts\secondapp>gulp servce
Build target: DEBUG
[12:30:43] Using gulpfile C:\spfxwebparts\secondapp\gulpfile.js
[12:30:43] Task 'servce' is not in your gulpfile
[12:30:43] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
[12:30:43] Task 'servce' is not in your gulpfile
[12:30:43] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
About to exit with code: 1
Process terminated before summary could be written, possible error in async code
 not continuing!
Trying to exit with exit code 1

Comment: You made a spelling mistake , make it `gulp serve` :)

Comment: @Gautam Sheth :Sorry   now  executed the correct  **gulp serve** command and got the same  error as above  image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the screenshot, i see that you are running the `Node v6.9.4` . You should uninstall this Node version and instead install the `Node v4.6.0 LTS` version. Today SharePoint Framework requires Node.js 4.6.0 to run, in future it may run on the latest and greatest version of Node, but right now you should install `v4.6.0` to get it running.

Download link - [Node v4.6.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.6.0/)

I have it installed and its running smoothly.

[image]

**Update**

As Sergei mentioned, its incompatible with typescript 2.0.xx.

You can also try below command and then run gulp serve again:

```
npm install @types/lodash@4.14.50
```

[SPFx Web Part will not compile - lodash errors occur](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/397)

Comment: I am getting the  same error with the node version 4.6.0. I updated the image in the question with the  node version 4.6.0

Comment: Thanks  for your answer  **npm install @types/lodash@4.14.50** was worked  for me. Now able to  see the output in workbench

Answer (score 5):

Recent changes in `lodash` module made it incompatible with `typescript 2.0.x`.

You can either upgrade `typescript` to `2.1.5` by running `npm install typescript --save-dev` or install previous definitions for `lodash` by removing `node_modules/@types/lodash`, and running `npm install @types/lodash@ts2.0`.

More info [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14384)

PS. welcome to "awesome" web-frontend world.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer  **npm install @types/lodash@4.14.50** was worked  for me. once again Thank you..

Comment: installing typescript 2.1.5 fix d thsis for me.