# SharePoint Framework MS github samples typescript errors

Tags: sharepoint-framework

Using the [MS github SharePoint Framework samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples)- I am seeing lots of typescript errors when running gulp serve

```
[18:04:39] [typescript] **Using custom version: 2.0.10** <br>
[18:04:39] Finished subtask 'copyStaticAssets' after 1.23 s<br>
[18:04:39] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 1.26 s<br>
[18:04:43] Error - typescript - 
node_modules\@types\angular\index.d.ts(1036,40): error TS1005: ']' expected.
<br>
[18:04:43] Error - typescript - 
node_modules\@types\angular\index.d.ts(1036,41): error TS1005: ')' expected.
<br>
[18:04:43] Error - typescript - 
node_modules\@types\angular\index.d.ts(1036,42): error TS1131: Property or 
signature expected.<br>
    .......
    .......
[18:04:44] Project angular-multipage version: 1.0.0<br>
[18:04:44] Build tools version: 0.11.1<br>
[18:04:44] Node version: v6.11.1<br>
[18:04:44] Total duration: 9.49 s<br>
[18:04:44] Task errors: 96<br>
[18:04:44] Error - 'undefined' errored after<br>
"orchestration aborted"<br>
```

Some of the samples from their github work and it will show "using custom version 2.2 or higher" - but if it's a lower version, like 2.0.10 above, in the build toolchain it will error out with various typescript errors.

I've tried adjusting the lodash version mentioned here: [Typescript errors in SharePoint Framework webparts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/207235/typescript-errors-in-sharepoint-framework-webparts)

Also tried switching to node version 4.6 and it didn't work. I have node 6.11.1 now.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is type script version your using is lower then  node version.. So You can updated typescript to latest version and also upgraded  node to latest...

You can upgrade your node using [this link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Download latest typescript using [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258)